# Show image immediately after upload in sailsjs

Tags: upload, gruntjs, sails.js

I have form with upload field. After searching for a while, I just put uploaded files to folder ./assets/posts and it worked correctly.

In my app, when submit done, it should be reload current url and show new uploaded image. But it didn't. My sails app use linker to manage assets. So after 3 or 4 times I try to reload the page, image is showed.

How to show image immediately when I submit done?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55745438/5559741

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sails uses `assets` folder to store mainly the assets that are supposed to be precompiled and/or published, e.g. scripts, styles and minor images (icons, etc.). For images it means in most of the cases that upon `sails lift` they are being copied (including directory structure and symlinks) from `./assets` folder to `./.tmp/public`, which becomes publicly accessible.

So, the short answer to the question is: in order to become immediately accessible the images should be copied to `./.tmp/public/posts` (not to `./assets/posts`).

On the other hand, `./.tmp` folder is being rewritten during `sails lift`, and you probably don't want your uploaded images to disappear whenever the application restarts, so it makes sense to upload the images in a completely different folder, let's say `./attachments/posts` or whatnot, which in its turn needs to be symlinked from `./.tmp/public/images/posts` after the Sails are lifted. For example, in your `config/bootstrap.js` you can put something like

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , path = require('path');

module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {
  // Whatever else you want to bootstrap...

  var postsSource = path.join(process.cwd(), 'attachments/posts')
    , postsDest = path.join(process.cwd(), '.tmp/public/images/posts');

  fs.symlink(postsSource, postsDest, function(err) {
    cb(err);
  });
};
```

You can use [synchronous version](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_symlinksync_srcpath_dstpath_type) of [fs.symlink](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_symlink_srcpath_dstpath_type_callback) or [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to create multiple links.

**Update for windows guys**

```
var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('mklink /j '+postsDest+' '+postsSource , function(err, stdout, stderr){
    cb(err);
});
```

And, of course, even better way would be uploading the images directly to a CDN/storage service (Amazon S3, etc.) and just generating corresponding URLs to access them.

Comment: Hi, if I upload to ./attachments/posts, then how to get link from view? thanks a lot!

Comment: If you upload to `./attachments/posts`, the images can be served via URLs like `http://your.site.com/images/posts/image001.jpg`, but only after you create a symlink, something like `mkdir -p ./.tmp/public/images && ln -s ./attachments/posts ./.tmp/public/images/posts`.

Again, since this command must be applied every time the Sails are lifted, it makes sense to do it from within your code, for example, from your `config/bootstrap.js`: `module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) { ... require('fs').symlink('<source_path>', '<dest_path>', function(err) { cb(err); }); };`

Comment: My error on Windows 7 x64: `{ [Error: ENOENT, symlink 'd:\Learn\nodeapp\attachments\posts']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'd:\\Learn\\nodeapp\\attachments\\posts' }`

Comment: Well, running Node on Windows is really not the best idea. But if you have no choice, then forget the symlink thing and just put your files directly in `./.tmp/public/images/posts`. They'll be gone after Sails is restarted, but I guess you can deal with it on development stage.

Comment: Thanks @bredikhin, I will switch to Linux to solve this issue.

Comment: @anhnt Wise decision, by all means. ;)

Comment: I found solution for windows users. `var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var path = require('path');
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) { var sourceFolder = path.join(process.cwd(), sails.config.anhnt.uploadPath);
  var symlinkFolder = path.join(process.cwd(), sails.config.anhnt.tmpPath);

  exec('mklink /J '+symlinkFolder+' '+sourceFolder , function(err, stdout, stderr){
  cb(err);
 }); };`. Should be updated to your answer to help windows guys like me :)

Comment: @anhnt Nice! Try editing the answer yourself, it should work. Or I'll do it if it didn't. ;)

Comment: Your answer didnt work for me... the clean grunt task keeps removing the symlink after bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, which is OS agnostic, is to change the grunt-clean task (in /tasks/config/clean.js) to specify which folders to clean in your .tmp/public. See example below. In my case, I created a folder "uploads" in .tmp/public, and it does not get deleted.

```
grunt.config.set('clean', {
    dev: ['.tmp/public/fonts/**','.tmp/public/images/**','.tmp/public/js/**','.tmp/public/js/**','.tmp/public/styles/**','.tmp/public/*.*'],
    build: ['www']
});
```