# Grunt converts symlink to folder in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, sails.js

Im, trying to upload files with sails.js in production, my error is when i upload the file i cannot get it back because grunt has to compile it, i have been trying to create a symlink in the assets folder based in the same problem of this answer: [Image not showing immediately after uploading in sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450795/image-not-showing-immediately-after-uploading-in-sails-js)

But when i lift the server in production grunt converts the symlink into a folder in .tmp

someone knows how to get the symlink in grunt? im using sails 0.11.0

**SOLUTION:**

i have found a solution to this problem, i had to configure nginx so it serves the static files:

```
upstream server {
  server 127.0.0.1:8008;
}

server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name server.com;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/server.com.log.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/server.error.log debug;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://server;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

  }

  location /uploads {
    root /home/server/project;
    access_log        off;
    expires           30d;
  }
}
```