# access uploaded images - sails.js

Tags: sails.js

i have managed to upload an image to my localhost.its current location is in myApp/.tmp/uploads.

how can i acces it from: view/file/upload.ejs? (the view has the uploaded files params such as filename, size etc...)

i have tried `<img src="..\..\.tmp\uploads\<%= items[0].filename %>" alt=""/>`

and this: `<img src="..\..\.tmp\uploads\<%= items[0].filename %>" alt=""/>`

and this:`<img src="\.tmp\uploads\<%= items[0].filename %>" alt=""/>`

i think the problem is because <%= items[0].filename %> shows me the name of the file when i pick it up from the directory but although its real name is a long random word.

Answer (score 0):

To show image you uploaded with default skipper settings, this should work:

```
<img src="uploads/<%= items[0].filename %>" alt=""/>
```

Skipper uploads it to .tmp/public/uploads.
The problem is that when you relift sails or your app gets restarted, .tmp will be deleted so you should do something like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128144/show-image-immediately-after-upload-in-sailsjs)

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a view that handle this folder and i would hardly recommend you to move the files to another dir because .tmp may be cleared from while to while.

Comment: how can i create an ejs view that will display that image and how can i change where the image files go to beacause they are in going to .tmp by default